# Keep logo in the center and maintain ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After one hour of trying to figure this out with multiple version of jquery I give up.
I have a navigation menu which has a logo in the center I need the logo to always be a circle. Since the layout is responsive I set the height of the logo based on the width that has been generated for it. The problem is that whenever I change the viewport size the logo moves out of place height wise and I have no clue on how to maintain it.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehxptLft/42/)

[Fiddle result here](http://jsfiddle.net/ehxptLft/42/embedded/result/)

Currently there are 5 buttons in the navigation menu so each button has 20% width. 
Then I set the height and ofset the logo like this

```
function scaleLogo(){

    var ww = $(window).width();
    if (ww < 300) {
      var cr = 0.05;
    }
    else {
      var cr = 0.30;
    }  

    var cw = $('#home_btn').width();
    $('#home_btn').css({
        'height': cw + 'px', 
        'top': '-' + cr * cw + 'px'
    });
}
```

So the `'height': cw + 'px'` sets the height to the size of the width and `'top': '-' + cr * cw + 'px'` sets the top attribute to minus cr(circle ratio) times cw(circle weight) which results in positioning it either -10% of width when screen width is less than 400px or -30% of width when above 400px.

The issue is that this only kind of works when I switch to my phone or full hd desktop pc and scale to little width,the viewport gets very thin and tall making the logo not centered at all.

I'd be very much grateful for any tips or advices on how to successfully center the logo no matter the width or height of the viewport.

I was trying to force min width on the body like `body{min-width:600px}` and I assumed that when I would change the window width to less than 600px it would stop scaling the contents, but it didn't do anything. If anyone could explain this I'd appreciate that as well.

As always, looking forward to your replies.
Thank you.

Comment: Modern day browsers - background image with background-size and background-position.

Comment: oh ok. I'll try to play with that then. Will come back when I get some results. Thank you. Wait actually not, because the button is still gonna be positioned wrongly. I don't have an issue with the image but the circle button.

Comment: And/or use [a unit like `vw`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) to solve it in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a very simple solution: instead of position your logo using percentages from the top, position it with a fixed percentage and reduce by half the pixel size you already calculated. This worked in your fiddle:

```
 $('#home_btn').css({
    'height': cw + 'px',
    // steadily position it in the middle
    'top': '50%',
    // then reduce its top margin with half its height
    'margin-top' : -(cw/2) + 'px'
 });
```

Comment: oh wow. After today I am starting to think I have this problem where I approach everything with really complicated solutions :'(. Thank you. Any chance you also know how I could set the minimum width?

Comment: When you are talking `min-width` of a page, its best to use a container div and give that a `min-width`, as the `body` issue... If it doesn't work setting a `min-width` on it, then I'm unsure why. However, there are no devices viewing pages smaller than 200px, so I wouldn't really worry as this works to very small sizes. You could, however, declare `font-size` in `rem` and then modify your `font-size` based on viewport width...

Comment: I just realized something. With this method when you click on the circle it moves it out of place. I guess I'll have to set the margin for :active with jquery now as well then?? Check here http://jsfiddle.net/ehxptLft/57/ it was supposed to move the circle 3px down and reduce the amount of shadow so it created the pressed in effect.

Comment: But is there even a jquery equivalent of css :active ?

Comment: solved it by adding the below code right underneath the code you have provided :) Prolly not the best solution tho $('#activeStyle').remove();
    $('head').append('<style type="text/css" id="activeStyle">#home_btn:active {margin: -'+ (cw/2-3) + 'px 0 0 !important;background: rgb(221, 221, 221);-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgb(119, 119, 119), 0 2px 0 0 rgb(119, 119, 119), 0 3px 0 0 rgb(119, 119, 119), inset -5px 0 5px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.91), inset 10px 0 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.91), 0 6px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.81);}</style>');

Comment: Uhm.. The jauery esuivalent is `is("active")` I think. Your is a dirty solution though, try to _not_ use active is this case. I dont really see what the point of active is. Just dont define the margin etc.. in active and you should be fine anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea with positioning the logo with CSS and not worrying about positioning the image

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    var winWidth = $(this).width();
    var logoSize = Math.ceil(winWidth / 4);
    $(".logo").width(logoSize).height(logoSize);
});
```

```css
.logo {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(211,211,211);
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Same code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0rLwh4w3/ where you can actually resize the browser

Comment: This is a nice way to do it, but it doesn't seem to solve the centering issue, its just another way of displaying it. Nice CSS work, though.

Comment: Thought issue was with image, not the actual circle, that could also be fixed with CSS.